# I have been trying to install drupal recruiter module but each time i get this error

Tags: drupal

```
> "An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging
> information follows. Path:
> http://localhost/recruiter/install.php?profile=recruiter&locale=en&id=1&op=do
> StatusText: OK ResponseText: ( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum execution time
> of 120 seconds exceeded in
> C:\wamp\www\recruiter\includes\database\database.inc on line 2139 Call
> Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0040248632{main}(
> )..\install.php:0 20.0160607192install_drupal( )..\install.php:26
> 32.26217145128install_run_tasks( )..\install.core.inc:77 414.388825262480install_run_task( )..\install.core.inc:339 514.390825347848_batch_page( )..\install.core.inc:449 614.391825363584_batch_do( )..\batch.inc:80 714.391825363824_batch_process( )..\batch.inc:161 814.394825451928call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\recruiter\includes\batch.inc:284}
> ( )..\batch.inc:284 914.394825452000_install_module_batch(
> )..\batch.inc:284 1014.394825452792module_enable(
> )..\install.core.inc:1571 1117.022025873824module_invoke(
> )..\module.inc:484
> 1217.022025874176call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\recruiter\includes\module.inc:833}
> ( )..\module.inc:833 1317.022025874456recruiter_job_search_enable(
> )..\module.inc:833 1423.273328866048_features_restore(
> )..\recruiter_job_search.install:17 1523.324328868808features_invoke(
> )..\features.module:871
> 1623.324328869392call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\recruiter\profiles\recruiter\modules\features\features.module:516}
> ( )..\features.module:516 1723.324328869880field_features_rebuild(
> )..\features.module:516 18119.471832102680field_create_instance(
> )..\features.field.inc:192 19119.911932112584module_invoke_all(
> )..\field.crud.inc:499
> 20119.916932115264call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\recruiter\includes\module.inc:857}
> ( )..\module.inc:857 21119.916932115584views_field_create_instance(
> )..\module.inc:857 22119.916932115792cache_clear_all(
> )..\views.module:898 23119.916932115792DrupalFakeCache->clear(
> )..\cache.inc:176 24119.916932115792DrupalDatabaseCache->clear(
> )..\cache-install.inc:57 25119.916932116800TruncateQuery->execute(
> )..\cache.inc:521 26119.916932117016DatabaseConnection->query(
> )..\query.inc:932 27119.917932118608DatabaseStatementBase->execute(
> )..\database.inc:664
>
```

I have tried increasing maximum execution time in php.ini but still
get this error any help will be appreciated"

Comment: Pls! any one with help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you increased the maximum execution time did you checked whit phpinfo() if it is really increased.

One more thing check this -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: I just checked and found out that it did not change aferal

Comment: But i changed it from bin/php/php.ini inn my wamp installation directory

Comment: And did you than restarted the wamp server? Sorry for the question

Comment: I just found out that wamp has two php.ini files on in the apache folder and the other in the php folder.

Comment: I guess that is were my problem is coming from

Comment: Trying to see if this fixes my problem

Comment: Thank you for your response. And i don't regret joining Stackover flow today

Comment: No problem and i'm glad if i helped you. You could also vote the comment if it was helpful. Have a nice day and don't stop using the Stackoverflow

Comment: I am trying to develop a job portal and i am using recruiter as the base for the site

Comment: my problem is i dont like the way it is looking i want to redesign the page and remove some text on the pages